# Wrappper class in test class

Tags: unit-test

Getting Difficulty to Cover this Wrapper Class.......

```
public class filterWrapper{

        public string selectedFilter{get;set;}
        public string selectedFilterField{get;set;}
        public string filterValue{get;set;}
        Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Lead').getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        public filterWrapper(string selectedFilterField, string selectedFilter , string filterValue){
            this.selectedFilterField = String.valueOf(fieldMap.get(selectedFilterField));
            this.selectedFilter = selectedFilter;
            this.filterValue = filterValue;
        }
}
```

Comment: What all you need to do is create an instance of the class in test method and refer the variable not there in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
filterWrapper fw = new filterWrapper('FirstName', 'First Name', 'Bob');
```